# Creacion de un Crud con C# usando phpmyadmin 2.10.3 como base de datos

Tags: c#

quisiera saber si es posible crear algo así como lo dice el titulo, lo estoy creando a modo de practica con el lenguaje, necesito ayuda!!!!

He revisado tutoriales pero todos me dicen que hay que utilizar My Sql server, ademas cuando intento alguno, ninguno me conecta con el servidor.

Ya descargue un cenector y nada.

Comment: Deberías leer [ask]

Comment: en realidad seguramente lo que necesitas es MySQL como base de datos, el conector lo encuentras en la pagina oficial  [https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/] y en la web existen muchos tutoriales de como hacer un crud con .net (c#) y MySQL, una vez que lo hagas, tus datos los podrás ver en phpmyadmin. Saludos!